# WCF - using objects from a third dll via webservices

Tags: wcf

I have the following project structure:
Project B has DataContract objects.
Project A has a web service endpoint and a project references to Project B.

WS Client:
Has a web service reference to Project A. However, it doesn't see any objects defined in Project B.
I am wondering how can I make the objects defined in Project B visible to web service client. Do I need to create a WSDL by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If project B's DLL contains the classes, and if you want the clients to use the classes, then they will have to be given the DLL.

If, instead, you want the clients to have access to *proxy classes* that correspond to the actual classes, then you must reference them in the Web Service contracts. Proxy types will not be generated for anything that is not part of the contract.

Comment: John, Yes, I want the client being able to reference the proxy classes. I tried svcutil and it seemed to do the job. Is there a better way of generating a proxy?

Comment: "Add Service Reference" is what most people use.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a reference to the Project B from within your client app and then update web reference.

Comment: Pavel, Project B's DLL will not be distributed to client users so it can't be added as a reference.